# colspan + fixed width content influence td width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem with either my understanding of `colspan` or the browsers implementing `colspan` in a HTML table. See the following example:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="upper-td" colspan="2">
      <div style="width:500px">colspan</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="broken-td">col 1</td>
    <td id="fullwidth-td" style="width:100%">col 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

From my understanding, the `#upper-td` should not influence the width of the lower `td`s because of the `colspan=2`. This is what happens in Firefox.

In Chrome, IE11 and Edge, the `#broken-td` has an offsetWidth of 250px (precisely a width of 248px and 1px padding to left and right). This is precisely half the width of the content of the `#upper-td` (I tested with multiple widths and this ratio stayed).

**Can someone explain this behavior?**

Workarounds are to set `#broken-td{width:0}` (works in IE, not in Chrome) or `#broken-td{width:1%}` (works in Chrome, not in IE). But a user-agent sniffing workaround is the last thing I'd like to introduce to our codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Firefox renders it correctly, looks like a bug in Chrome and IE, but not sure about that. As a workaround, using [`<col>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col) element seems to be working well across the different browsers.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vq8Lhsco/)**

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-1 {
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <col class="col-1">
  <col class="col-2">
  <tr>
    <td id="upper-td" colspan="2">
      <div style="width:500px">colspan</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="broken-td">col 1</td>
    <td id="fullwidth-td">col 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The upper row really doesn't influence the width of the lower one: It's width is the default 100%. (check it in the browser tools), the 500px setting is more or less independent from that.

The rather strange division of the lower row is due to the 100% width setting of its second cell (which relates to the width of the `tr`): It tries to span the full width, but cannot completely, since the contents of the first cell *have* to be displayed, which is done with the smallest possible width, which is achieved by using a line break, so that cell has the width of its longest word.

See also http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xORBXO

(edit: I added two varations to the codepen: The settings are always the same, ust the width of the wrapping element, which could also be the viewport itself is different: 500, 400 and 600px;)

Comment: Thanks! I don't get the "which is achieved by using a line break" part. Why is the smallest possible width not the width of the string "col 1"?

Comment: If you would put a `&nbsp;` between 'col' and '1', it would be that way, but the widths of the cells in a table are either defined "manually" (as in your `#fullwidth-td`  or automatically, according to the contents, which are evenly distributed by breaking text into lines so that all cells more or less have the same hight. Your second row is a mixture between defined and automatic widths: Since `#broken-td` theoretically has 0%  width, its contents are made as narrow as possible by using a line break.

Comment: Ah, it gets closer. So there is a line-break inserted between "col" and "1" to make it as small as possible. Makes sense. But why does it then get a width of 250px where it would only need the width of the string "col"?

Comment: Apparently Chrome and others (i.e. not Firefox) ignore the percentage width of cells if not ALL cells have a percentage width. Which is actually quite logical. See this variation of the same codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KMNYgV The first cell has 25%, the second no width: Both become equally wide. If you add/uncomment the 75% width for the second cell, the percentages work.

Comment: P.S.: The 'colspan'  has nothing to do with it. The only thing it does in this example is set the overall width of *both* columns to 500px.

Comment: I understand the logic of Chrome ignoring not explicitly set widths (like in my example). In Chrome setting 1% and 99% widths for the second row works as expected. In IE however, it stays the same. IE on the other hand is fine with 0px and 100%, which Chrome does not respect.